# Filter array of dictionaries based on value

Tags: python, python-3.x, list-comprehension

I am certain that this has been answered, but I can't find an example and am having trouble figuring it out.

I have an array of dicts. Each dict has a list of teams.  I want to filter the array where the team id is not in the list. For example:

```
items = [{'teams':[{'id':'a'}]}, {'teams':[{'id':'b'}]}, {'teams':[{'id':'a'},{'id':'b'}]}]
```

I want to filter the array to get only the teams where id is 'b':

```
items = filter(items, ...) -> [{'teams':[{'id':'b'}]}, {'teams':[{'id':'a'},{'id':'b'}]}]
```

I tried this, but didn't work:

```
items = [a for a in items if lambda x: 'b' in x['teams']]
```

And

```
items = filter(items, lambda x: 'b' in x['teams'])
```

This didn't work because x['teams'] is a list of objects.

I would like to either use filter or list comprehension.

Comment: A simple way to make this problem easier to solve on your own would be to write out the `lambda` as an actual function. (Also has a side effect of being self documenting.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're half way there. You can use `any` and a generator expression to check if 'b' is in the teams.

```py
items = [{'teams':[{'id':'a'}]}, {'teams':[{'id':'b'}]}, {'teams':[{'id':'a'},{'id':'b'}]}]
```

```py
output = [
   team
   for team in items
   if any(t['id'] == 'b' for t in team['teams'])
]
# [{'teams': [{'id': 'b'}]}, {'teams': [{'id': 'a'}, {'id': 'b'}]}]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `any()` with the inner list to search for teams where `any` inner team has the id you want:

```
items = [{'teams':[{'id':'a'}]}, {'teams':[{'id':'b'}]}, {'teams':[{'id':'a'},{'id':'b'}]}]

search = 'b'
list(filter(lambda item: 
        any(team['id'] == search 
        for team in item['teams']), items)
)
# [{'teams': [{'id': 'b'}]}, {'teams': [{'id': 'a'}, {'id': 'b'}]}]
```

Of course, you can do this as a list comprehension too if you don't need the lazy evaluation of filter.

Comment: Your whitespace usage makes this really hard to read. Additionally you'd just use a generator expression if you "need the lazy evaluation of filter".

Comment: A generator expression would be no different, that's the point.

Comment: Reminds my of an old joke: 'Q: How many developers does it take to change a lightbulb? A: 10: one to change the lightbulb and nine others  tell him how they would have done it better'. If your generator is the answer you should *submit an answer*. Downvoting working solutions that answer the question is in pretty poor taste.

Comment: Nice, I've not come across that version of the joke.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a function to check if there's a particular team within some list of teams:

```
def contains_team(teams, key):
    return any(team["id"] == key for team in teams)
```

And here's one way to use it:

```
items_with_team_b = [x for x in items if contains_team(x["teams"], "b")]
```